# Domain names not resolving @ Debian VPS

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, resolv.conf

I have a quite common problem except all the solutions I've found didn't work for me.

I had my VPS, running Debian 5/Debian 6/CentOS 5.5/*whatever-else-OS-I've-tried*, rebuilt and reinstalled. Once started, the network works fine, and I can ping IPs, `8.8.8.8` for example. The problem here is that the VPS can't resolve hostnames.

First of all, the default `resolv.conf` looks fine:

```
vps:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Those hosts are set by default by my VPS provider. The file does not get rewrited. And the default version is restored on every reboot.

**UPDATE** The [`8.8.8.8` server](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/) works, I've tried it on my home PC. As well as I've tried my home ISP's DNS server on that VPS -- still no success.

As I've already said, ping works fine as well:

```
vps:~# ping -c 4 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=7.63 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=7.55 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=7.08 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=7.30 ms
```

Here's what the `/etc/hosts` file looks like:

```
vps:~# cat /etc/hosts
::1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
*my-actual-IP-goes-here* example.com  vps
```

**UPDATE** The contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
vps:~# cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

The `/etc/network/interfaces` file has the 100% working backed up version of config, and I can see that in the `ifconfig` output. The `/ver/log/syslog` file doesn't say anything relevant, except the

> sm-mta[1443]: gethostbyaddr(*my-actual-IP-goes-here*) failed: 2

**UPDATE** `bind` is installed:

```
vps:~# apt-cache policy bind9
bind9:
  Installed: 1:9.5.1.dfsg.P3-1+lenny1
  Candidate: 1:9.5.1.dfsg.P3-1+lenny1
  Version table:
 *** 1:9.5.1.dfsg.P3-1+lenny1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Do you have *any* resolver running?

Comment: Hey! What do you mean, `bind` and so on? Yeah, forgot to mention: there's no `bind` or (I'm pretty sure) other software with same functionality installed. However, how do i double-check?

Comment: if you haven't any resolver, you get exactly "...the VPS can't resolve hostnames..." in order to resolve you must have answers for "who" and "where". `netstat -na|grep 53`

Comment: I guess you're right: the output of the above command is empty. I'm gonna manually add my nearest Debian mirror to `/etc/hosts` file and `apt-get` one.

Comment: Tried `apt-cache policy bind9` and realised I already have it installed, it just wasn't running for some reason. `/etc/init.d/bind9 start` made something to appear in the `netstat -na|grep 53` output, mostly tcp & udp LISTEN on my external and local IPs. But I'm afraid resolving still doesn't work.

Comment: `nslookup www.google.com` + `traceroute www.google.com` - test, not afraid

Comment: What hostname are you trying to resolve and what is your IP address? I'm asking this just to check that it is actually a resolvable one.

Comment: No need to delete this question, the steps can be useful for other people.

Comment: I'd like to see the output from `dig -t a www.google.com @8.8.8.8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got up in the morning and everything works. I did nothing else to VPS except what I mentioned in my updates and comments. So I guess that was external issue in the DC.

And now, since everything works, that's pretty much "happy end".
Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Glad to hear it works. Remember to come back and accept your answer, otherwise the question keeps coming back for people to continue to try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is /etc/nsswitch.conf set to use DNS resolution?

Just another thought, have you verified that the DNS server is functioning and configured properly (not demonstrated in your information provided)?

Comment: thank you for your reply. Well, thats Google DNS service and it's supposed to work... But, well, yeah before I found out that's a Google service, I've tried that 8.8.8.8 server on my home PC with Windows's built-in nslookup utility, and yeah, it works.

Comment: And the contents of your /etc/nsswitch.conf file?

Comment: Here they are: http://i.imgur.com/ZlYOL.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dig` to trouble-shoot your current dns woes (`apt-get install dnsutils`)

Also to actually use your bind install you'll need to point your `resolv.conf` at it:

`nameserver 127.0.0.1`